# Arduino to serial +python to firebase UTF-8 decode error

Tags: python, c++, utf-8, arduino, firebase

Stack Overflow gods I ask for your mercy...

my error: ^[[A?????????????????????????????????????????q????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????c?????????????????????????????????????,23:24:05,01/06/2015,ourfleet

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ourfleet.py", line 33, in <module>
    result = requests.post(firebase_url + '/' + gps_location + '/gps_c.json'+ auth_token, data=json.dumps(data))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I am passing GPS data through serial from an arduino uno. This is UTF-8? Why is this happening?

My Arduino code:

```
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
/*
   This sample sketch demonstrates the normal use of a TinyGPS++ (TinyGPSPlus) object.
   It requires the use of SoftwareSerial, and assumes that you have a
   4800-baud serial GPS device hooked up on pins 4(rx) and 3(tx).
*/
static const int RXPin = 4, TXPin = 3;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

// The TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;

// The serial connection to the GPS device
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);
}

void loop()
{
  // This sketch displays information every time a new sentence is correctly encoded.
  while (ss.available() > 0)
    if (gps.encode(ss.read()))
      displayInfo();

  if (millis() > 5000 && gps.charsProcessed() < 10)
  {
    while(true);
  }
}

void displayInfo()
{
    Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);
    Serial.print(F(","));
    Serial.print(gps.location.lng(), 6);
    Serial.println();
}
```

My Python code that sends the data through https. I am also getting an error that is saying the connection is not https and, instead, it is http. I have tried to update my Python libraries using pip etc etc to no avail. I am using an 07 MacBook pro)

```
import serial
import time
import requests
import json

firebase_url = 'https://ourfleet.firebaseio.com'
auth_token = '0sBNZjz4uQvLteDoCZTDUD3RNOT852aKyqahGzl4'

#Connect to Serial Port for communication
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.wchusbserial410', 9600, timeout=0)

#Setup a loop to send GPS values at fixed intervals
#in seconds
fixed_interval = 10

while 1:
    try:
        #GPS value obtained from Arduino + Ublox
        gps_c = ser.readline()
        #current time and date
        time_hhmmss = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        date_mmddyyyy = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

        #current location name
        gps_location = 'ourfleet'

        print gps_c + ',' + time_hhmmss + ',' + date_mmddyyyy + ',' + gps_location

        #insert record

        data = {'date':date_mmddyyyy,'time':time_hhmmss,'location':gps_c}

        result = requests.post(firebase_url + '/' + gps_location + '/gps_c.json'+ auth_token, data=json.dumps(data))

        #insert record
        print 'Record inserted. Result Code = ' + str(result.status_code) + ',' + result.text
        time.sleep(fixed_interval)
    except IOError:
        print('Error! Something went wrong.')
        time.sleep(fixed_interval)
```

I am lacking the know how on this subject to modify my programs accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In your Python code, the first character of the data being read from the serial port is `'\xff'` in which case `json.dumps()` will throw the exception shown:

```
>>> json.dumps({'gps_c': '\xffblah'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

The data read from the serial port looks corrupted - it should be 14 bytes long (6 lat + 6 lon + `','` + `'\n'`), however, the data printed shows that it is far longer than that.

I suspect that the baud rates are not properly matched. In your C/C++ code you set one port to 155200 and another (`SoftwareSerial`) to 9600. The Python code expects 9600. Are you sure that you have configured the correct speeds?